# Help with Dialect file in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have begun creating a dialect for Interbase 7 in NHibernate.

Interbase SQL includes an operator `CONTAINING 'foo'` which is the equivalent of `LIKE '%' + 'foo' + '%'` in other flavours of SQL. `LIKE` is case sensitive in Interbase whereas `CONTAINING` is not, so I would like the dialect to translate `LIKE` situations to use `CONTAINING` instead.

I've had a really good look at example dialect files but I can't find anything relevant there. Can anyone provide any pointers?

Comment: If you manage to complete this project, would you be able to post it up somewhere?

-another person using interbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to replace internal uses of LIKE with CONTAINING (except patching NH).

You need to call CONTAINING explicitly. Once you've registered it, it's available as just another function in HQL, using Projections.SQLFunction in Criteria, and by writing the corresponding generator in LINQ (see http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'UPPER' to convert both side of the strings to Upper Case.

http://www.ibprovider.com/forum/site/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24